# Every time I generate a string, then close the program and generate again its the same

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, code-generation

Well I have made this random string generate but I have recently noticed a fatal flaw. When I generate a random string, close the program and generate another random string it is the same as the first generation. Here is the code:

```
   Public Function RandomString(ByVal length As Integer) As String
    Dim strb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim chars() As String = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"} 

    Dim UpperBound As Integer = UBound(chars)

    For x As Integer = 1 To length
        strb.Append(chars(Int(Rnd() * UpperBound)))
    Next

    Return strb.ToString

End Function

Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    Try
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Link Removed!")
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim repeatCnt As Integer

    'Check for valid numeric entry
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, repeatCnt) Then
        For repeatIdx As Integer = 1 To repeatCnt
            Dim rndstring As String
            'Generate random string...
            rndstring = RandomString(24)
            '...and append to text box with a line break
            RichTextBox1.Text &= rndstring & vbCrLf
        Next
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid integer number in the text box")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're running Rnd() instead of using the [Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) class.

In order to keep `Rnd()` from giving the same sequence of "random" numbers every time, [Random.Next()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b3ta19y.aspx) should be called (in order to use the machine clock for the initial value / seed).

So in your case:

```
Dim random As New System.Random()
Public Function RandomString(ByVal length As Integer) As String
   Dim strb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
   Dim chars() As String = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"} 

   Dim UpperBound As Integer = UBound(chars)

   For x As Integer = 1 To length
      strb.Append(chars(Int(random.Next(UpperBound)))
   Next

   Return strb.ToString

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you but now when I want to generate 10 random string it generates the same string 10 times. For example, if I generated HFJDSHDSDFSDSSDF it would show 10 times.

Comment: Move the creation of the random variable to outside the function, like I updated in my demo

Answer (score 0):

Try generating a random string like this:

```
Public Shared Function GeneratePass() As String

    Dim unique As Guid = Guid.NewGuid
    Return unique.ToString.Substring(1, 6)

End Function
```

Comment: This method can only yield digits 0-9 and letters a-f which is not what the OP wanted.

Comment: Yeah, just an idea that i thought *might* be useful.